# Cannot modify stored procedure of restored database because source database had replication running

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, compiler-errors, replication

I have restored the database from backup of production in DEV Server.

Prod Server has multiple replications running on the database. But I have neither configured any replication in the DEV nor have any plan to do so.

But when I modify a stored procedure on DEV database, I get following error:

> Msg 21531, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSmerge_alterschemaonly,
>   Line 50
>   The data definition language (DDL) command cannot be executed at the Subscriber. DDL commands can only be executed at the Publisher. In a republishing hierarchy, DDL commands can only be executed at the root Publisher, not at any of the republishing Subscribers.
>
> Msg 21530, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSmerge_ddldispatcher, Line 191
>   The schema change failed during execution of an internal replication procedure. For corrective action, see the other error messages that accompany this error message.
>
> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_MyName_Get, Line 37
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

I would be grateful if someone informs me the solution to this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
sp_removedbreplication 'database_name'
```